# Clustering with unknown number of clusters

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I need to find logins that belong to the same person. The task should be solved in python environment. 
I have a dataset with user actions. From these actions I created the N number of features:

```
- login
- timestamp
- feature 1
- feature 2
    ...
- feature N
```

Also, there is a training dataset with pairs of logins, which is most likely belonging to the same person.

```
- login_A 
- login_B 
- person_id
```

How to implement an algorithm that would break my dataset of logins that are being of the same person. As a result, I need to get a list of logins and some generated person_Ids.
Please help to find a proper method to tackle the problem and link to an example of implementation in Python.

Thank you!

Comment: Try DBSCAN method. It doesn't need knowledge about number of clusters in the dataset.

Comment: If you just want to traverse the set of pairs to find all logins that likely belong to the same person, then you may as well got with a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), repeated until all logins have been covered. On the other hand, if you want an actual clustering algorithm, try [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [Agglomerative clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Agglomerative_clustering_example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not incredibly well-versed in in this sort of thing, but my thought would be that you assign the cluster centers to be the midpoint between the two logins for each person and give each cluster the label of the person_id's logins it was created from. Then when you are classifying, you find the closest cluster center and assign that login to be that person id.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to try some algorithms of the [sk-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) clustering module `sklearn.cluster`. There are many available, among the most common clustering algorithms you'll find on the market. And it is really easy to use, you can run quite complex clustering algorithm with a couple of lines of code.

Some of them require the number of clusters beforehand, but it is not the case of all of them.

For example, hierarchical clustering can be used to obtain any number of clusters (there are nice explanations on [this page](https://stackabuse.com/hierarchical-clustering-with-python-and-scikit-learn/)).
You also can use DBSCAN if having lonely points which do not belong to any cluster does not bother you.

Edit: from the description of your problem, I'm not sure that clustering is what you want to do. In the case of a big community of users, we'd use clustering to build a few communities of people (clusters) who have some common points, and are rather similar to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have *training* data.

Then a **supervised** approach will always outperform an unsupervised approach such as clustering. It's the wrong tool for your problem.

Learn to classify whether two actions belong to the same user, or not.